# How to open network files from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

How can I open network files from Chrome? Due to security reasons, it does not allow to open local as well as network files. Is there a way to open network files with a single click?

Comment: Questions about Web browsers belong on [su].

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which network protocol, which OS?

Comment: Windows OS, local network files("file://")

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida

> Allows opening file:// links on pages loaded by http(s):// scheme